# How does Computers Handle Memory Addressing when the Max-memory is not on Power of 2?

Tags: memory, ram, memory-address

I know how Basic Memory Addressing works and why it's always recommended we use a amount of memory that is on a Power of 2, ( Explanation for future people ) because the bits used by the CPU to address the memory only have 2 values. So 2 bits can address 4 values, 3 can address 8, and so N bits can address 2^N values.

What happens then, when i have a different number? For instance, let's say i have 160GB of Memory installed on a Server ( 10x16GB ).

Assuming we need X amount of bits to address 128GB of RAM, will the CPU only use X bits on addressing and ignore the addresses available from "129 to 160" or will it use X+1 bits and have some invalid addresses? Instead of Invalid Addresses, will it use those as virtual RAM?

It can even use as reserved values for all i know, but i really would love to understand what happens.

Comment: When OSes were 16bits, they used EMM `extended memory manager` to allow addressing beyond 16 bits. Then when OSes were 32bit they were able to address 4GB of memory and any memory outside of 4GB are not used at all, with the exception of Win32, where it was only using 3GB. Now with 64bits the max memory is actually in terabytes. Whenever the memory is bigger than the addressable memory, the CPU has no way of reaching those beyond the size it can address.

Comment: CPU is bound by hardware bit width while OS is bound by software bit width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a PC for this answer, since it depends on the platform much more than the CPU.

It doesn't work anywhere near that simply. But to begin with,

> will it use X+1 bits and have some invalid addresses?

It will always use all bits, the CPU doesn't even care about invalid addresses, you can use them. It doesn't even know, so it cannot care.

Who *does* know is the BIOS, and it will tell you ("you" being the OS, presumably) what the landscape of the linear address space looks like with a couple of BIOS interrupts. The old one that detects only "low memory" was fairly simple, it just tells you how much memory there is, and leaves it up to you (the landscape wasn't as complicated then, so this sufficed). The "new" one (hardly, but comparatively newer), INT 0x15, EAX = 0xE820, will give you an actual map, which has the form of a list of ranges of linear address space along with descriptions.

You won't find that all actual RAM is mapped in a nice contiguous range that starts at 0. It will be mapped in chunks, separated by holes where for example memory mapped devices are mapped.

And since there are holes in the "low addresses" (though "low" is relative), some of the real RAM can get pushed "up". So if you have 4GB of RAM, some of it will be mapped to addresses higher than 0xFFFFFFFF. Where the holes actually are depends though. Read the memory map.

As an example, the map might look like this:

[image: memory map]

First column is starting address, second column is size, last column is type. Type 1 is normal RAM, type 2 isn't RAM, type 3 has stuff in it that you want to read but you can use it after you're done with it, or so the description says. There are a couple more types too. This map was produced in VirtualBox by giving it 4GB of RAM. It doesn't exactly add up to that though. Point is, you can see the holes.

If there is much less RAM, the second type 1 range would be shorter, but the rest would look the same (on VirtualBox anyway, elsewhere it will often look a bit different) - those type 2 ranges near the 32bit boundary will still be there, and there will just be a bunch of "nothing" mapped directly below them.

So, it's nowhere near as simple as using some number of bits in addresses.